# How do I reproduce invisible unicode characters?

Tags: unicode

I have a `\u200f` that's causing issues from a web form and want to reproduce it on my development environment to try to fix it, but I'm not sure how to insert this character since its invisible and can't be copy and pasted.

Any ideas?

Deceze answered for me; it was, naturally, invisible :)

[image]

Comment: Depends on your system and/or language. You can type something like `"\xE2\x80\x8F"` in most programming languages for the UTF-8 byte sequence for U+200F.

Comment: This would be on a web form. So OSX. I want to make sure my special case handling of that character is working.

Comment: Can't you just add it to the textbox/textfield content when sending the form? That will allow an untouched submit to sent it back.

Comment: Joachim what do you mean? I basically need to type in 500[insert \u200f here] into a form element.

Comment: On OS X, open the Character Viewer (accessible in most applications through the Edit menu) and type "200f" into the search field. That'll bring up the character (you won't see it, but it's the first item in the search results) and you can drag and drop it into a document.

Comment: @deceze; genius! You got it. Want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On OS X, open the Character Viewer (accessible in most applications through the Edit menu or in the input method selection menu, if you have that activated) and type "200f" into the search field. That'll bring up the character (you won't see it, but it's the first item in the search results) and you can drag and drop it into a document.

[image: IME menu]
[image]

Comment: The Character Viewer is the single best reason why OS X is so much more productive for programmers than certain other OSs... `</flamewar>` ;-)

Comment: Trying to drag and drop into an input and it doesn't seem to be working...  OS X 10.10.3.  Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect OS X to have some generic character insertion utility, similar to [UnicodeInput](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/unicodeinput/index.htm) for Windows.

But for just testing a form, you can edit the page containing the form so that the input field is prefilled, and there you can use character references, e.g.

```
<input ... value="500&#x200f;">
```

Comment: The **Unicode Hex Input** source, added from _System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources_, lets you type arbitrary codes by holding down ⌥ (Option/Alt) and typing the four hex digits.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite old, but as reference in latest Mac OS Releases, add the Unicode Hex Input Keyboard as shown below:

[image: Unicode Hex Input Keyboard]

Choose from the list:

[image: List]

And with **Option(⌥)** key pressed, type `200f` as shown in other comments.